# Resizing image with Graphicsmagick in Nodejs generates emty file

Tags: node.js, azure, imagemagick, azure-blob-storage, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to resize an existing image and then upload it to Azure storage, but no success yet ...

```
gm("https://sinkroon.blob.core.windows.net/sinkroonboilerplate/dakterras1.jpg")
.resize(50, 50)
.stream(function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    var writeStream = blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob(
    containerName,
    'test.jpg',
    { contentType: 'image/jpg' },
    function (error, result, response) {
         if (error) {
             console.error(error);
         } else {
         }
    });
    stdout.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

This generates an empty image : https://sinkroon.blob.core.windows.net/sinkroonboilerplate/test.jpg

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong ... Anyone ?

Comment: Perhaps a permission issue where the image file is getting written.

Answer (score 2):

For this case i use this:

```
var request = require('request');
var lwip    = require('lwip');
request({url: url, encoding:null}, function (err, response, imageBuffer) {
    var imageFormat = response.headers["content-type"].match(/(png|jpg|jpeg)/)[0];  
        lwip.open( imageBuffer, imageFormat, function(err, image){
            if (err || !image) throw err;
            image.resize(196, 196, function(err, image){
                if (err || !image) throw err;
                image.toBuffer(imageFormat, function(err, buffer){
                     //here you buffer you can save image in file with FS
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```